# AAD/B2C Custom SignUp - Using Auth Code Flow - How can I get MSAL to exchange code with id and refresh tokens?

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-msal, adal

We have a custom signup process using custom policies.

We have implemented Auth Code Flow and have set the Sign Up button to navigate to the following URL (obfuscated a bit):

https://SampleApp.b2clogin.com/SampleApp.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?p=B2C_1A_SampleApp_SIGNUP&client_id=ffffffff-3d49-46b9-9e82-7d1cefa3c0c6&nonce=defaultNonce&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fuat.SampleApp.org.au&scope=openid&response_type=code&prompt=login&code_challenge=YTFjNjI1OWYzMzA3MTI4ZDY2Njg5M2RkNmVjNDE5YmEyZGRhOGYyM2IzNjdmZWFhMTQ1ODg3NDcxY2Nl

Now, we do get a code back from AAD/B2C, but how do we get MSAL to do the exchange for the tokens and push them into the desired cache for us?

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

[Authorization code flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/authorization-code-flow#1-get-an-authorization-code) requires there to be a resource/scope to redeem an access token for. You have not provided any scope that corresponds to a resource, hence there is nothing to redeem for.

MSAL would do this all automatically if you have an appropriate scope configured in your MSAL Authentication Parameters object.

Follow [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/configure-authentication-sample-spa-app#step-2-register-your-spa-and-api) to create the resource API Application registration, expose and grant access to a scope to your front end.

Then [add your scope](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/configure-authentication-sample-spa-app#31-update-the-spa-sample) to the MSAL config.

Comment: Hi Jas, thanks for your reply, I'm sorry as I may not have been clear in my question. Now, I'm performing a SignUp request and am passing in a scope as 'openid'. I'm not after an access token to call an api, rather I'm after MSAL providing me the required id tokens after SignUp in exchange for the code that is returned post SignUp redirect call.

Comment: For the interim, we are redirecting the SignUp request to a local SignIn component and perform an MSAL instance.loginRedirect() process again. Although not sure if this is the correct approach.
Assumption is that if we get redirected to the SignIn page, we are deemed to get an authentication done. Will also be handling errors if in case the signup request wasn't successful for any reason.

Comment: You need to follow my answer, MSAL.js does not request `response_type=id_token token`, it requests `response_type=code`, and for `code` to be redeemed, you need a **resource**. Create a dummy resource if you will never use the access token. When the auth code is redeemed, the id_token is returned. Only the hybrid flow, or pure OIDC flow requests `response_type=id_token`, where an id token is returned directly to the app. Settings `scope=openid` does not mean an id token is returned directly, it depends on the `response_type`.

Comment: Thanks for the update Jas, will follow on your answer and create a dummy resource and check further.